# Javascript : Get all cookies with domain name as x.y.com

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a requirement to retrieve and clear cookies tat are set buy my site. However, when I fetch the cookies by `document.cookie` I get the parent domain's cookie as well.

Eg :

```
CookieA : Doamin x.y.com (Set by x.y.com)
CookieB : Domain y.com  (set by c.y.com)
```

I there any way I could filter the cookies by domain name?
Right now, in chrome console, when I query `document.cookie`, I do not get the domain name.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: well technically y.com is your site.... ;)

Comment: Answer is, there is not much you can do other than know what cookies you set for your subdomain and manually remove those.